# Run batch with java return error

Tags: java, batch-file

I need send parameter and execute batch file from java code. I used this method:

```
private void run(){
        if (atmUsernameField.getText().length() > 0 &&
            atmPasswordField.getText().length() > 0 &&
            serverURLField.getText().length() > 0){

            String atmUsername= atmUsernameField.getText();
            String atmPassword = atmPasswordField.getText();
            String url = serverURLField.getText();
            String userHomePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
            userHomePath = userHomePath + File.separator + "INFOKIOSK" + File.separator + "device_jar";
            String fileName = userHomePath + File.separator + "restart.bat";
            if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_XP || SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
                try {
                    String processID = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
                    int endIndex = processID.indexOf("@");
                    processID = processID.substring(0, endIndex);
                    new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start " + fileName, processID, atmUsername, atmPassword, url).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the restart.bat:

```
TASKKILL /F /PID %1 /T
cd /d %~dp0
java -jar device.jar --atm.autoload.page=%4 --atm.username=%2   --atm.password=%3 -debug
```

restart.bat need at first killed process where PID = processID 
and go to folder where is located he 
and running device.jar with parameters.
When I runnin this code on Windows 7 machine, code is worked. If running on Windows XP SP3 machine return error "Not Found C:\Documents ...."
I need running this code on Windows XP machine. where the error is, why the code does not work?

Comment: Well ... "Not Found C:\Documents ..." it can't find your file. your file may be 'Documents\My Documents' but that space means that Java will see it as: 'Documents\My'. so check the path

Comment: @Stultuske I did not use the path "C:\Documents".  File are in directory: user.home\INFOKIOSK\device_jar\restart.bat. Only, in the old version of the artifact I used this path. Maybe what that cache hinders a job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userHomePath` contains spaces on winXP.
On Win7 it does not anymore.

Try to add quotes as shown below, it will work in either environment:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start \"" + fileName + "\"", processID, atmUsername, atmPassword, url).start();
```

Maybe you'll need to add quotes in your .bat too

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, userHomePath in WinXP:  "C:\Documents and Settings\Username\" ->   for this  output error "Not Found C:\Documents"